# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to delete an indexed property from 'CSSStyleDeclaration'

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer un tipo de botón para seleccionar diferentes estilos como se muestra en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
const options = document.querySelectorAll(".options");
const circle = document.querySelector(".circle");

console.log(options);

for(let option of options){
    option.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
        let optionSelected = e.srcElement.id;
        console.log(circle.style);
        
        if(optionSelected === "option1") {
            if(circle.style[0] === undefined) circle.style.left = "6px";
            else{
                delete circle.style[0];
                circle.style.left = "6px";
            };
        };
        if(optionSelected === "option2") {
            if(circle.style[0] === undefined) circle.style.right = "35%";
            else{
                delete circle.style[0];
                circle.style.right = "35%";
            };
        };
        if(optionSelected === "option3") {
            if(circle.style[0] === undefined) circle.style.right = "6px";
            else{
                delete circle.style[0];
                circle.style.right = "6px";
            };
        };
    });
};
```

Creé cuadrados invisibles (`.options`) dentro del contenedor para así, cuando haga clic el usuario, se seleccione la opción correspondiente y mover el círculo, pero a la hora de querer eliminar la propiedad anterior (`right` y `left`) con `delete` me salta el siguiente error:

> *Uncaught TypeError: Failed to delete an indexed property from 'CSSStyleDeclaration': Index property deleter is not supported.
> at HTMLDivElement.*

También, si hay una forma mas óptima de realizar esto, agradecería que me lo comparta.

Comment: Leyendo el mensaje de error, y al tratarse de CSS, me parece que en lugar de `delete` estás buscando utilizar el método [`removeProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/removeProperty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como bien dice padaleiana en los comentarios tu problema es por usar `delete`, creo que lo más fácil es setear las propiedades con `unset` Algo así:

```
circle.style.left = "unset";
circle.style.right = "unset";
if (optionSelected === "option1")
{
    circle.style.left = "6px";
};
if (optionSelected === "option2")
{
    circle.style.right = "35%";
};
if (optionSelected === "option3")
{
   circle.style.right = "6px";
};
```

Pero tu problema nace porque estas usando `left` y `right` al mismo tiempo para el circulo. Si lo hicieras todo en relación de uno solo, no tendrias este problema. Por ejemplo solo usando `left`

```
if (optionSelected === "option1")
{
    circle.style.left = "6px";
};
if (optionSelected === "option2")
{
    circle.style.left = "12px"; //valor de ejemplo
};
if (optionSelected === "option3")
{
    circle.style.left = "24px"; //valor de ejemplo
};
```

Y por último, el uso de javascript tampoco es necesario para realizar lo que buscas, esto se puede realizar a partir de solo CSS:

```css
.selectorControl{
  display:flex;
  position:relative;
  background-color:#3A4764;
  color: white;
}

.selectorControl label{
 cursor:pointer;
 text-align:center;
}

.selectorControl label:after{
 content:'';
 display:block;
 height:20px;
 width:20px;
 background-color: #232C43;
}

.selectorControl label:nth-child(1):after {
  border-radius: 50% 0 0 50%
}
.selectorControl label:nth-child(3):after {
  border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
}


.selectorControl input[type=radio]{
 display:none;
}

.selectorControl .bola{
 height:18px;
 width:18px;
 border-radius:50%;
 background-color: #D03F2E;
 position:absolute;
 bottom: 1px;
 transition:all 0.4s;
}

#select1:checked ~ .bola{
  transform:translateX(0px);
}
#select2:checked ~ .bola{
  transform:translateX(20px);
}

#select3:checked ~ .bola{
  transform:translateX(40px);
}
```

```html
<div class="selectorControl">
  <label for="select1">1</label>
  <label for="select2">2</label>
  <label for="select3">3</label>
  <input type="radio" name="unnombre" id="select1" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="unnombre" id="select2" >
  <input type="radio" name="unnombre" id="select3">
  <div class="bola"></div>
</div>
```